# How to hack the compiled Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: macos, chromium-embedded

I have an installed application which uses CEF to display web content on my mac. I didn't make the application. I want to access developer console in the application. Is there a way to turn on debugging mode in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

1. Start the application with a command line argument
   `--remote-debugging-port=9222`
2. Using Chrome go to `http://localhost:9222`
3. If you are able to connect click on the link of interest. It'll open Chrome Developer Tools.

If the developers didn't take special measures this way is likely to succeed.
More details [here](https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html).

Comment: I succeed to run the application with the argument, `--remote-debugging-port`. But I got following error.  

    Uncaught TypeError: Object.observe is not a function
        at WebInspector.Main._createSettings (inspector.js:10392)
        at WebInspector.Main._gotPreferences (inspector.js:10384)
        at WebInspector.InspectorFrontendHostStub.getPreferences (inspector.js:1352)
        at WebInspector.Main._loaded (inspector.js:10383)
        at windowLoaded (inspector.js:677)